# All symbols in this file are wrong

Tags: math-mode

[image]

I'm using XeLaTeX to build my homework but the commas and the parentheses are all messed up. Could someone explain this?

Source code:

```
4). $(1,5,6,2,3,10,4,7,1)$ is a cycle of length 8.

5). Since $\{3,4\}$ is not an edge and $(3,10,4)$ is a path, the length of a shortest path from 3 to 4 is 2.

6). The vertices you can travel to from 8 within 2 edges are 2, 3, 9, 10. Since $(8,3,2,7)$ is a path, the length of a shortest path from 8 to 7 is 3.

7). $(4,7,1,5,2,6)$ is such a path.
```

Comment: sorry that was a bug please do an update and it will go

Comment: Bug in what package?

Comment: @newcworld001 A low-level one (`unicode-math`)